# Best way to 'flatten out' tables with relationship information?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table, Relationships, structured as so

```
Relationships 
------
Relationship Employer_ID Employee_ID
10000        10020       10021
10001        10019       10020
10002        10021       10018
```

where the relationship between an employer and an employee is uniquely identified by the relationship column. An employee can have multiple employers, and an employer can have multiple employees. Each person has their own unique ID -- which can appear multiple times in both the Employer and Employee ID fields.

and another table, Review, structured as so.

```
Meetings Review 
------
Meeting   Attendee_ID
10000     10020     
10000     10019
10001     10018
10001     10021
```

This table shows a list of meetings and attendees. Only two people can attend a meeting -- each meeting attendee, for a meeting, is represented once in the Attendees field. The IDs in the Attendee field can be joined with the IDs in the Employer/Employee field in the Relationships table.

I'd like to get a result set as the following -- where each row is a unique meeting, and we have identified the relationship between the two meeting attendees by using two separate columns (Employer_ID and Employee_ID).

```
Results
-----
Meeting Employer_ID Employee_ID 
10000   10019       10020
10001   10021       10018
```

My question is -- conceptually, how would I go about doing this?

My initial thought is that I should just use maximum and minimum on the Attendee_ID, and then make two derived tables -- one where the maximum attendee ID (Attendee_1) matches matches on the Employer ID and the minimum ID (Attendee_2) matches on the Employee ID. Then, use a UNION query to add this result set to another derived table where the maximum attendee ID (Attendee_1) matches on the Employee ID and the minimum ID (Attendee)2) matches on the Employer ID.

This does appear to give me the results I expect, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your meetings seem always to be meetings of exactly one employee and their employer (which is why you can show employer and employee per meeting). So why then does your meeting table not simply have one record per meeting with the according relationships number?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two element for each Meeting  i think the best solution is the second alias

```
Meetings Review 
------
Meeting   Attendee_ID
10000     10020     
10000     10019
10001     10018
10001     10021
```

you can obtain the result on a single rows this way

```
select a.Meeting , a.Employer_ID b.Employer_ID 
from Review  a 
inner join Review b  on a.Meeting = b.Meeting  and a.Employer_ID != b.Employer_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, the relationship between two attendees is determined by the records in the `Relationships` table - I don't think you can assume that there is some magical meaning in whether the IDs are larger or smaller. Your sample data shows this - 10020 is the employer of 10021, but 10021 is the employer of 10018.

So, you're looking for records in `Meetings Review`

where the `meeting` column is the same,

and one value matches a record where the `attendee_ID` is the `employer` from `Relationships`,

and the other value matches a record where the `attendee_id` is the `employee` in `Relationships`,

and both records from `Relationships` have the same `Relationship` value.